# filter irregular blobs with opencv for OCR improvement

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I'm trying to extract handwritten text from an image to enable ocr. My forms contain textboxes so it is not too complex to get the right regions of interests, but the problem is most people have issues to stay within the boundaries of the boxes. While I can increase the area to cover for this, the result is that I get my string, and some part of the box above and beyond.

Like below image

[image]

Depending on the level of pollution on top or bottom of the picture, the OCR software happily ignores, or adds random nonsense. So in order to be safe I need to get rid of as much as possible, while at the same time I need to keep my 'full' letters intact to ensure there is enough quality left for the OCR part.

The expected output should just show ITEGEM (which is a small place in Belgium, nothing fancy here)

like this :

[image]

I've been trying a few things, but standard blob detection is too harsch as it also removes part of the first T, as there are a few pixels between the top of the T and the base of the T, so I get left with I instead of T.

Any suggestions to get me back on track (preferably python)?

Comment: "standard blob detection is too harsh": blob detection is detecting blobs and their properties. It's not harsh, sor soft. What are you doing with the detected blobs? Show this with some code.

Comment: You could try finding connected components and filter them by area

Comment: you could deal with that *before cropping*. those are *pieces of* strokes from adjacent lines. associate glyphs into lines.